# How much will AJAX affect the server if it refreshes every second?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I am currently planning to create a separate system that will allow users to view a list of employees that entered the work area with the help of a facial recognition device. However, I am planning to use PHP, Laravel, and AJAX as a programming language. How much will AJAX affect the server if I program it to refresh every second to fetch current data from the database and update the employee list?

Comment: If you do it every second, you're server will be overwhelmed by the requests. If you still want to refresh it real-time keep the ajax poll time between 5-10 seconds which will give the server enough time to actually service the request & return a response. In case you feel 5-10 seconds is too long to wait, then if you do it every 2 seconds you'll have to wait for an existing ajax call to finish before you try to initiate a new `AJAX` call.

Comment: Also if you need it to be real time you could look into using socket.io  that would allow the data to be pushed through a socket directly to the app that’s listening for the new information. Definitely a bit more complicated but the preferred method if you need it to be real time.

Comment: 1. Do you really need every seconds? 2. how many clients will do those requests? 3. Can your server can take it? 4.Definitely a job for [Laravel Echo](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/broadcasting#installing-laravel-echo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, but isn't a good approach. Use Laravel Echo instead: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/broadcasting

Simply broadcast your changes across users and update their UI.

To make your life more easy use Vue (optionally with Vuex).